# How to use the same UIDatePicker to get Date and Time in 2 UITextField by separate

Tags: objective-c, xcode, datepicker, uitextfield, picker

I'm working in iPad Application and I have a Picker in One XIB, I wanna use the same UIDataPicker to get by separate the date in one UITextField and The Time in a different UITextField.

Example:

UItextField_1 > Here I wanna get only the date
UItextField_2 > Here I wanna get only the time

UIDatePicker > I wanna this picker (only ONE) to get both  values.

Some ideas to achieve it?

Any idea is welcome, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up an event listener using UIControlEventValueChanged in your viewDidLoad method.

```
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(action:forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Then in that handler you could do something like this:

```
- (void)action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // Date
    dateTextField1.text = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[datePicker date] dateStyle:kCFDateFormatterShortStyle timeStyle:kCFDateFormatterNoStyle];

    // Time    
    dateTextField2.text = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[datePicker date] dateStyle:kCFDateFormatterNoStyle timeStyle:kCFDateFormatterShortStyle];
}
```

[Note: this is untested code. It's only meant to give you an idea of what to do]

Comment: Excellent Answer, This example was useful. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

you just have to get the date from the UIDataPicker and use NSDateFormatter to separate the values ex

```
-(IBAction) endDate{

//gets date only 01/01/2011
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.dateStyle = kCFDateFormatterShortStyle;
NSLog(@"%@",[df stringFromDate:endByDatePicker.date]);

//gets time h:mm
NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm"];
NSLog(@"%@",[outputFormatter stringFromDate:self.endByDatePicker.date]);

}
```